# Vector space structure on $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field and $F\in k[X,Y]$ irreducible such that $F(0,0)=0$. Let $\mathcal{O}$ the local ring of the plane curve $F$ at $P=(0,0)$ and suppose that $P$ is a simple point of $F$. Suppose that the tangent line of $F$ at $P$ is $Y$ and that the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}$ is $\mathfrak{m}=(X)$.

Note that for $n\ge 1$, $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}$ has two $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space structures.

1. **Induced from the inclusion of $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$:** we have an inclusion $$\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}\to
       \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}$$ given by $[f]\mapsto [fX^{n-1}]$, so
   $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}$ is a $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$-vector
   space.
2. **Induced from the $K$-vector space structure of $k[X,Y]$:** The quotient ring $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$ is isomorphic to $k$
   through the map $[f]\mapsto f(0,0)$. In this point of view, we can also consider the natural $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}$-vector space structure of $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}$ given by
   $$\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}\times \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}\to \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}$$
   $$([f],[g])\mapsto [f(0,0)g].$$

Are those two structure the same (or is there any mistake in the above reasoning) ?

I remarked that since $F=Y+X(\dots)$, we have that
$$[f(X,Y)X^{n-1}g]=[f(0,Y)X^{n-1}g]=[(f(0,0)+Y(\dots))X^{n-1}g]=[f(0,0)X^{n-1}g]$$
in $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m^n}$, but this isn't exactly the second action.

Comment: It seems to me that the first action is on the "last coordinate" and the second is a "diagonal action" if I'm interpreting your maps correctly. If you think of $\mathcal{O}/\frak{m}^n$ as tuples $[g]=(b_0, \ldots, b_{n-1})$ where $b_i$ is the coefficient of $X^{i}$ for $g$, then the first map is $a_0\cdot [g]= (b_0, \ldots, a_0 b_{n-1})$ and the second is $a_0\cdot [g]= (a_0b_0, \ldots, a_0b_{n-1})$.

Comment: To give a bit more context to the question: in the notations above, we define for example the Hilbert-Samuel polynomial as $f(n)=\dim_K(\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}^n)$, where the $K$-action is the second one. However, for any discrete valuation local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, the polynomial is defined as $\dim_K(\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}^n)$ with $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$ and the first action. I was wondering whether these definition were consistent.

Comment: Your map $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}^n$ is not a ring homomorphism, so it does not give the second ring the structure of a module over the first.

Comment: Dear Klaus, Just to add to Pete's comment above, and Andrew's answer below, your first map does not give a vector space structure.  The only natural $k$-vector space structure that exists in this context is the second one your consider.  Regards,

Answer (score 5):

Your first construction does not in fact determine a vector space structure on $\mathcal O/\mathfrak m.$ It simply defines an isomorphism between $\mathcal O/\mathfrak m = k$ and the subspace generated by $X^{n-1}$ in $\mathcal O/\mathfrak m^n,$ which coincides with scalar multiplication on the vector $X^{n-1}$ under the vector space structure on $\mathcal O/\mathfrak m^n$ defined in the second construction.

Let's consider an example. If $F=Y-X^2,$ then $$\mathcal O=(k[X,Y]/F)_{(X,Y)}=(k[X,Y]/(Y-X^2))_{(X,Y)}=k[X]_{(X)},$$ which consists of elements that are quotients $f/g$ with $f,g\in k[X]$ and $g(0)\neq 0.$  So $\mathfrak m=(X)\subseteq \mathcal O.$

It is not hard to see that $\mathcal O/\mathfrak m^n=\operatorname{span}_k\{1, X,X^2,X^3,\ldots,X^{n-1}\}.$ Then the map from the first construction takes an element $f/g\in\mathcal O/\mathfrak m$ to the element $(f(0)/g(0))X^{n-1}.$ Clearly we have said nothing about scalar multiplication on the elements $1,X,X^2,\ldots, X^{n-2}$ here however.

But, if we take the collection of these isomorphisms from $1,\ldots,n-1$, then they together give the scalar multiplication we're after on all of $\mathcal O/\mathfrak m^n$.